# Hadoop WordCount example - Implementing Sorting

Tags: hadoop

I'm  a Hadoop newbie. I have been able to successfully run the WordCount example.

I would like to modify this example such that my output is sorted in ascending order of count. I'm unable to figure out where I would need to make the necessary changes.

It would be great if someone would give me some direction to implement sorting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `org.apache.hadoop.examples.Sort`

This is not super-straightforward to do using map/reduce.  It involves taking a histogram of your data and using the `TotalOrderPartitioner`.

Alternatively, you can use Hive or Pig, which has built-in functions for sorting.

Comment: Thanks! I looked at Hive and that seems like a potential solution.